# Jquery datepicker beforeShow doesn't seem to be passing the instance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is the JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UEnqL/

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', beforeShowDay: myFunction});

function myFunction(input, inst)
{
    alert(inst);
}
```

According to the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Datepicker#event-beforeShow

the `beforeshowDay` method accepts input and inst. inst always seems to be undefined though. This is causing me some grief as I need to get hold of the datepicker itself.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you confusing `beforeShow` and `beforeShowDay`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `beforeshowDay` callback has only one argument; a `date` object as per documentation. the `beforeShow` callback however has 2 arguments as you've mentioned.

`beforeShowDay` - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Datepicker#event-beforeShowDay

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/UEnqL/6/

As you can see, the `beforeShow` callback correctly passes in the element and the instance. The `beforeshowDay` passes in just a date object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about `beforeShow`, not `beforeShowday`.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UEnqL/9/) is the fiddle.